# PyPDF2 returns only one line per character

Tags: python, pdf, text, pypdf

I am currently trying to read and extract text from research papers (PDFs). I have tried using PyPDF with the following code:

```
import PyPDF2

pdfFileObj = open('my_research_paper.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
print("Number of pages:-"+str(pdfReader.numPages))
num = pdfReader.numPages
i =0
while(i<num):
    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(i)
    text=pageObj.extractText()
    text1 = text.lower()
    for line in text1:
        print(line)
    i= I+1
```

The problem is that the output from that is only one character per line so that it makes it hard to process whole sentences.

This is the kind of output I get from [this file](https://trackr-media.tangiblemedia.org/publishedmedia/Papers/653-OTQxO/Published/PDF):

```
t
h
a
t
c
a
n
b
e
h
a
v
e
i
n
a
n
o
n
-
d
e
t
e
r
m
i
n
i
```

Would anyone know why it does appear like that and why I can't get proper line that are easier to process. The ideal for me would be to get sentences from the pdf so that I could then look for some specific words in these sentences and count their occurrences.

Comment: Can you print `text1` and see what it contains?

Comment: @mckuok it contains the exact same thing... You can easily reproduce my problem with the code I gave you and the paper I gave you in the post. I think I followed the MWE recommendations :). It's late here for me so I'll try to reply tomorrow.

Comment: From what I read on the function `extractText()`, it returns `a unicode string object.`, not each line. So the behavior you observe makes sense

Comment: @mckuok but then how do you read line by line ?

Comment: It is very unfortunate that pdf format does not work that way. Spaces and lines are awful. I found [this](http://survivalengineer.blogspot.com/2014/04/parsing-pdfs-in-python.html) for you. Pdfminer does additional work to figure out spaces and lines.

Comment: @mckuok ok thanks for that I would look into it and share an answer it if I manage to make it work. I knew about Pdfminer before but it seem a hassle to install so I thought I would go for the much easier PyPDF2. Thanks for your answer

Comment: use a `virtualenvironment`, and `pip install pdfminer`

Comment: I have used Pypdf2 for doing NLP on Pdf's by converting them to text. Even though here it is printing a word by word in every line, I am pretty sure if you want to use regex or anyother thing on the extracted text it will work fine!!

Comment: @RahulAgarwal well here it is printing a letter per line, so that is really not fine. Especially since white spaces are removed

Comment: I have also tried it, and what you are saying is true. But I am hoping you dont want to just print information line by line..the end objective must be something else. So, if you try your end objective on "text" or "text1" it may produce the desired result!!